# What is the complexity of the following simple program?

Tags: c, time-complexity

I am having trouble finding understanding complexity. Could someone help me understand what the complexity of the code below is and why.

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { // (n is a number chosen by the user)
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        printf("i=%d, j=%d", i, j);
    }
}
```

An explanation would be great.

Comment: What do you think it is and what are you having trouble with? Do you know how to estimate the "complexity" of *any* program?

Comment: What is the initial value of  `i`?

Comment: What do you *think* the complexity is? Why do you think that?

Comment: Complexity theory is usually discussed in terms of variable input. For you the input is fixed.

Comment: First thing be specific what type of complexity? I think you want time complexity in this case. For the given program think of it as a no of times your printf statement is being executed. Please refer to CLRS to learn about complexity

Comment: You updated your question twice, changing the potential answers.  It is recommended to modify the question only by adding **EDIT** paragraphs to keep the discussion meaningful.  I updated my answer to make the explanation thorough and consistent, but try and follow good usage in future questions.

Answer (score 2):

*Original Question*: Because `i`'s initial value is undefined, the behavior of the code is unpredictable. There is no way to usefully answer the question other than that the complexity is undefined. There is no way to know how many operations the code will perform.

*Updated Question*: It's O(1). The code will always do precisely the same amount of work.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have fixed it.

Comment: You didn't fix it, you made it a completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the time complexity of this code fragment by evaluating the number of operations, namely the number of calls to `printf()` which for simplicity's sake we shall assume to be equivalent:

Assuming `i` starts at `1` (you initially forgot to initialize it), the outer loop runs 99 times, for each iteration, the inner loop runs `i` times.  Gauss was supposedly 9 years old when he computed the resulting number of iterations to be `99 * (99 + 1) / 2`.

The complexity of the original piece of code was **O(1)** since it did not depend on any variable, but since instead you updated the code as:

```
void fun(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            printf("i=%d, j=%d", i, j);
         }
    }
}
```

The time complexity would come out as **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

Comment: The gaussian sum equation is `n*(n+1)/2`, so the number of iterations is `4950` if `n=100`.

Comment: @Frodo: thank you... I really ain't no Gauss.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming i starts at 0, the complexity would be constant. The complexity is always expressed relative to a variable defining the number of executions, which is not the case here.

If one term should be used to describe this behavior, it is "constant". There will be a number of executions, but this number will never change